# How to update the documentation of railsapps gh-pages?

Tags: railsapps

Regarding "railsapps"

The documentation page at http://railsapps.github.io/rails-application-templates.html
mentions a link to "https://github.com/quickleft/prologue"
which is a dead end.
How can I send a pull request to update the documentation so that

a) the link is removed OR
   b) the link is amended to point to a fork such as 
"https://github.com/forest/prologue"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your interest in updating the RailsApps documentation. It's been over four years since I've updated that page, so I'm sure much of the content is out of date.

There's a wiki page at
https://github.com/RailsApps/railsapps.github.com/wiki/rails-application-templates
that you can edit online. After making an edit, open an issue at https://github.com/RailsApps/railsapps.github.com/issues or just email me and I will push the changes to the gh-pages branch to update the static pages.